# JSP bean tag for property that might not exist

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, javabeans

In JSP I can reference a bean's property by using the tag
${object.property}

Is there some way to deal with properties that might not exist? I have a JSP page that needs to deal with different types. Example:

```
public class Person {
    public String getName()
}
public class Employee extends Person {
    public float getSalary()
}
```

In JSP I want to display a table of people with columns of name and salary. If the person is not an employee then salary should be blank. The row HTML might look like:

```
<tr>
    <td><c:out value="${person.name}"></td>
    <td><c:out value="${person.salary}"></td>
</tr>
```

Unfortunately if person is not an employee then it can't find salary and an error occurs. How would I solve this in JSP?

Edit: Is there an **instanceof** check in JSP tag language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the EL empty operator IF it was a scoped attribute, unfortunately you'll have to go with surrounding your expression using employee.salary with <c:catch>:

```
<c:catch var="err">
    <c:out value="${employee.salary}"/>
</c:catch>
```

If you really need *instanceof*, you might consider a custom tag.

Comment: I _knew_ there was an easier way... DOH!

Comment: Using Tomcat 5.5 this will throw an exception if the property doesn't actually exist on the object as in the case of the example shown above.

Comment: Confirmed, this does not work if person doesn't have a salary property.

Comment: My apologies for my carelessness. I hate to say it but you may have to use the c:catch tag for this.

Comment: +1 Worked for me as well. I wanted to know a `${pageContext["errorData"]` exist and a catch was indeed the only way to prevent an null pointer exception. I expected better from EL but here we are.

Comment: This has to be one of the stupidest things about JSP/EL, that the template code has to know the difference between beans and map instances. Thanks for the answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you want the class, just use `${person.class}`. You can also use `${person.class.name eq 'my.package.PersonClass'}`

You can also use the "default" on c:out.

```
 <c:out value='${person.salary}' default="Null Value" />
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  I use a <c:when> tag and the class' simpleName property and I can display each of my subclass's unique fields.

<c:when test="${instance.className.simpleName == 'MyClassName'}">

Answer (score 3):

Concise, but unchecked.

```
<tr>
    <td>${person.name}</td>    
    <td>${person.class.simpleName == 'Employee' ? person.salary : ''}</td>
</tr>
```

> Is there an instanceof check in JSP tag language?

Not at the moment of this writing. I read somewhere that they have reserved it, *instanceof* keyword, in EL, may be for future. Moreover, there is a library available that has this specific tag. Look into that before deciding to create some custom tag for yourself. Here is the link, [Unstandard Tag Library](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/sandbox/doc/unstandard-doc/intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to create a custom tag library and use polymorphism within it to handle the case where a `Person` *is-a* `Employee`.

I haven't done this in a while for JSP, but frequently use a similar technique in GSP (Groovy/Grails Server Pages).

Otherwise, you could put some logic in the `JSP` (not ideal) to test for `Employee`-ness:

```
<% 
   String salary
   if (person instanceof Employee) {
       salary = person.salary
   } else {
       salary = "" // or '&nbsp;'
   }
%>
<td><c:out value="${salary}"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always have a type field.

```
public class Person {
    public String getType() { return "Person"; }
    public String getName()
}
public class Employee extends Person {
    public String getType() { return "Employee"; }
    public float getSalary()
}
```

Your JSP would look like

```
<tr>
    <td><c:out value="${person.name}"></td>
    <td><c:if test="'Employee' eq person.type"><c:out value="${person.salary}"></c:if></td>
</tr>
```

Of course the Class class already has this...

```
<tr>
    <td><c:out value="${person.name}"></td>
    <td><c:if test="'Employee' eq person.class.simpleName"><c:out value="${person.salary}"></c:if></td>
</tr>
```

You could also have `isEmployee()' method.